# Provider error while posting to data to server (Using Chopper)

Tags: json, flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I get the following errors. I am using chopper flutter library and providers. I haven't used providers much. I am sending dummy data but on the form button click.

```
I/flutter (28363): Observatory listening on ************************************
E/flutter (28363): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'DateTime'
E/flutter (28363): #0      _JsonStringifier.writeObject (dart:convert/json.dart:688:7)
E/flutter (28363): #1      _JsonStringifier.writeMap (dart:convert/json.dart:769:7)
E/flutter (28363): #2      _JsonStringifier.writeJsonValue (dart:convert/json.dart:724:21)
E/flutter (28363): #3      _JsonStringifier.writeObject (dart:convert/json.dart:679:9)
E/flutter (28363): #4      _JsonStringStringifier.printOn (dart:convert/json.dart:877:17)
E/flutter (28363): #5      _JsonStringStringifier.stringify (dart:convert/json.dart:862:5)
E/flutter (28363): #6      JsonEncoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:262:30)
E/flutter (28363): #7      JsonCodec.encode (dart:convert/json.dart:172:45)
E/flutter (28363): #8      JsonConverter.encodeJson
E/flutter (28363): #9      JsonConverter.convertRequest
E/flutter (28363): #10     ChopperClient._encodeRequest
E/flutter (28363): #11     ChopperClient._handleRequestConverter
E/flutter (28363): #12     ChopperClient.send
E/flutter (28363): #13     _$PersonalPostingService.postPersonal
E/flutter (28363): #14     _FormState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>
E/flutter (28363): #15     _FormState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>
E/flutter (28363): #16     _InkResponseState._handleTap
E/flutter (28363): #17     GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback
E/flutter (28363): #18     TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp
E/flutter (28363): #19     BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp
E/flutter (28363): #20     BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture
E/flutter (28363): #21     GestureArenaManager.sweep
E/flutter (28363): #22     GestureBinding.handleEvent
E/flutter (28363): #23     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent
E/flutter (28363): #24     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent
E/flutter (28363): #25     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately
E/flutter (28363): #26     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent
E/flutter (28363): #27     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue
E/flutter (28363): #28     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket
E/flutter (28363): #29     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1370:13)
E/flutter (28363): #30     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1265:19)
E/flutter (28363): #31     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1170:7)
E/flutter (28363): #32     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:182:10)
E/flutter (28363): #33     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:282:7)
E/flutter (28363): #34     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:96:31)
E/flutter (28363):
Exited (1)
```

#### The following is my onPressed() method of the button

#### The form is just useless sitting there I am using hardcoded values in a map from another class

```
child: RaisedButton(
                                  onPressed: () async {
                                    final form = _formKey.currentState;

                                    if (form!.validate()) {
                                      form.save();
                                      //_user.makePostRequest();
                                      showNotification();
                                      await Provider.of<PersonalPostingService>(
                                              context,
                                              listen: false)
                                          .postPersonal(_user.data);
                                    }
                                  },
                                  child: Text('Save'))),
```

Comment: Use FutureBuilder. Sample link https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data.

Comment: i am posting, the fetch commands work fine in future builders